# How do I order dict by iterating list of uuids in django template language?

Tags: python, django-templates, uuid

I'm trying to order a dict by using a list containing the order uuids in django - how would I template this out?

`order = ['uuid1', 'uuid2']`

```
data = {
u'uuid1': {
    u'checked': False,
    u'deleted': False,
    u'last_change': u'2014-12-25 09:15:22.155000',
    u'text': u'Test.'
  },
u'uuid2': {
    u'checked': False,
    u'deleted': False,
    u'last_change': u'2014-12-25 09:15:22.155000',
    u'text': u'Test'
  }
}
```

How do I template this out?

```
{% for uuid in order %}
  {% for key, value in data|getkey:{{uuid}} %}
    {{ key }}
    {{ value.deleted }}
    {{ value.last_change }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: why dont you use `order = [data['uuid1'], data['uuid2']]` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {
u'uuid1': {
    u'checked': False,
    u'deleted': False,
    u'last_change': u'2014-12-25 09:15:22.155000',
    u'text': u'Test.'
  },
u'uuid2': {
    u'checked': False,
    u'deleted': False,
    u'last_change': u'2014-12-25 09:15:22.155000',
    u'text': u'Test'
  }
}

order = [data['uuid2'], data['uuid2']]
```

Then, django goes...

```
{% for uuid in order %}
  {% for key in uuid: %}
    {{ key }}{{ uuid[key] }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

To update:

```
data['uuid1']['checked'] = True
```

Comment: Thanks - I was a bit confused out the gate but I see what you're doing now so that works like a charm.